# make field a dropdown in access 2007

Tags: database, ms-access, field, office-2007

I'm creating a HR database in access 2007

I have a main table of employee info and several tables that relate to that table ( education for example) that list the acceptable elements that can populate that cell in that row

When i create a form it was created as just a plain text field which is constrained but I wanted to create a dropdown that had just the data that they are allowed to enter to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to right-click the text box and select Change To -> Combo Box.

Comment: While this is true, the answer does not deal with the problem of bound columns, record source, column count and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not familiar with creating controls, it is best to use the wizards. Select a combobox from the toolbox and add it to your form, you will be guided through creating the type of combo that you want.

You should also examine the relationships you have created.